# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 323

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner

For the Launch-4 request has nonce and state as dynamic values and these two dynamic values found in the previous request Launch-2 I can able to capture it  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezJ9k.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDfO.png)

When I run the test Launch-2 is getting 200 response button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HvTO.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtFlQ.png)

Launch-4 request is getting as ***java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 323:***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K0t9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr3kb.png)

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

The characters which can be used in URL are defined in [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), they are:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

others need to be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

So you need to tick `URL Encode?` box next to the parameter which can hold "problematic" characters or wrap the correlated value into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode), I guess it's either `nonce` or `state`

In general you can record your login attempt using [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and they will generate more or less good request which should work fine after correlation.

P.S. should method be POST?